# How can I trace water pipes and the water flow under the ground?

Tags: walls, pipe, gardening

I'd like to close the tube that from my garden go to the garage box. Is there any cheap way to figure out where the tubes are without dig the ground/walls?

Comment: Plastic or metal?  Metal perhaps you can rent an underground tracer.

Comment: Unfortunately, plastic

Comment: When you say "close the tube" what do you mean?  Can you not just cap it off on each end where you can access it inside?  Do you need to know where it actually runs?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is this a water pipe, or electrical conduit? What is the purpose of it? Why do you want to remove it; could you just cut off the end and leave the rest underground?

Comment: More info needed - electrical or water or what ?

Comment: @Lynnwood yes, i need to found the path, because one tube run out my home to a not anymore mine place and I need to close it

Comment: @Ken, Daniel, it's written in the title of the question: water (plastic) pipes =)

Comment: @Delayer - I was looking to see if that question was edited - can't believe I read right over "water" . Ok why not just disconnect it and close it off at the garage box ? The tools required to do what you desire Ground Penetrating Radar (GPR) is expensive to rent. A good divinator might be able to find it. If this was permitted - then there would be a map showing it perhaps at the city records division. See my out of the box answer is a bit clever if I say so myself .. ..in 5 minutes..

Comment: If you can turn the water on you can use a dowel touching your ear like a stethoscope and find the pipe, I have poor hearing but can still find both drains and supply pipes using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do to locate that plastic pipe under ground - I would disconnect it at your garage box, I would then insert a copper, aluminum wire of sufficient gauge to be able to feed into the pipe with out it curling up on you or you could run Electricians steel 'Fish Tape' .

At this point use a metal detector - you can buy them for about $100 - $200 U.S.

Now using the metal detector you can plot where that Plastic Pipe is located ..Very easily..

*Booyah!!..*

Answer (score 0):

can't you call your utility company to mark where things are underground?

Comment: This probably isn't the utility's pipe to begin with, so they wouldn't have a clue where it was...